# Avoid a prompt about change file mode in a Vim script

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make every file that start with shebang to be executable by default, so I use the following line in my vimrc,

`au BufWritePost * if getline(1) =~ "^#!" | silent !chmod a+x <afile>`

VIM asks me if I want to reload everytime I write the file:

[image]

Any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the VIM manual for Warning 16, you just need to add `autoread`. Take a look at the help info for it by typing, `:help autoread`.

Comment: Now that I have been playing with this for a while, I can't actually get your initial example to work. What version of VIM are you using?